# My first animated data grid with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, vue.js

Because this is my very first attempt to create a data grid with Vue, I would like to know about all misconceptions used in my approach. Whomever points to the most important shortcoming / weakness in my approach will receive 50 points :).

```js
var url ='https://api.mockaroo.com/api/b5f38710?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0'
new Vue({
  el: '#datagrid',
  data: {
    columns: {
      id: 'ID',
      nick: 'Nick name',
      first: 'First name',
      last: 'Last name'
    },
    users: [],
    query: '',
    prevKey: 'id',
    orderDesc: false
  },
  methods: {
    async loadUsers () {
      var result = await axios.get(url)
      this.users = result.data
      this.query = ''
      this.prevKey = 'id'
      this.orderDesc = false
    },
    clearQuery () {
      this.query = ''
    },
    sortUsers (e) {
      var key = e.target.dataset.key
      if (this.prevKey === key) {
        this.users.reverse()
        this.orderDesc = !this.orderDesc
      } else {
       this.users = _.sortBy(this.users, key)
        this.orderDesc = false
       this.prevKey = key
      }
    },
    filterUsers (users) {
      return _.filter(users, user =>
        _.find(user, prop =>
          new RegExp(this.query, 'i').test(prop)
        ) 
      )
    },
    updateQuery: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.query = e.target.value
    }, 350)
  }
})
```

```css
#datagrid {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #3F51B5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #263238;
}
.thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
.tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
.thead .td {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tbody .td {
  padding: 4px;
  color: #263238;
  text-align: center;
}
.tr .td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
.tbody .tr:hover .td {
  background-color: #C5CAE9;
}
.tbody .tr:hover .td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid #C5CAE9;
}
.tools {
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tools:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.source {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.search {
  float: right;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  transition: all .6s;
}
.asc {
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
}
.desc {
  border-top: 6px solid white;
}
.users-move {
  transition: transform .6s;
}
.users-enter-active, .users-leave-active {
  transition: all .6s;
}
.users-enter, .users-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="datagrid">
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="source" @click="loadUsers">
      Load some fake data from mockaroo.com
    </button>   
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" @input="updateQuery" :value="query">
      <button class="clear" @click="clearQuery">clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="thead" @click="sortUsers">
      <div class="tr">
        <span v-for="(col, key) in columns" class="td" :data-key=key>
          {{ col }}
          <span
            v-if="prevKey === key"
            :class="['arrow', orderDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc']">
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <transition-group name="users" tag="div" class="tbody">
      <div class="tr" v-for="row in filterUsers(users)" :key="row.id">
        <span class="td" v-for="column in row">{{ column }}</span>
      </div>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

**If the snippet doesn't load the data:** Mockaroo has an SSL certificate problem. So you must open [the data URL](https://api.mockaroo.com/api/b5f38710?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0) in your browser first, confirm the security exception, delete the downloaded JSON and then run this code snippet again.

Comment: Your "Load some fake data from mockaroo.com" doesn't appear to do anything. Did you check whether it still works as snippet?

Comment: @Mast Mockaroo have ssl certificatie problem. So you must open data url in browser first ( https://api.mockaroo.com/api/b5f38710?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0 ), confirm security exception, delete downloaded json a then run my code snippet again.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Please add that information to the question itself. Comments are kind-of third-rate citizens on the Stack Exchange network and may be removed in the future. Not having the note may get your question closed in the future ;-) I'm no JS expert, but I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 1):

###Feedback
Your code is really solid. It makes great use of async functions, arrow functions, transitions, etc.

###Suggestions
The only things I could think of that *could* be changed are:

1. Put the filtered users in a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). One could argue that the difference is small - it adds a couple lines, and the function is technically still called the same amount of times, but it takes the function call out of the markup.

   ```
    computed: {
        filteredUsers: function() {
          return _.filter(this.users, user =>
            _.find(user, prop =>
              new RegExp(this.query, 'i').test(prop)
            ) 
          ) ;
        }
      },
   ```

Then use that when iterating over the users:

```
    <div class="tr" v-for="row in filteredUsers" :key="row.id">
```

2. Since the code already contains arrow functions, continue with es6 features and use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) unless browser support is an issue. For reasons why, [see this answer on SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274352/244085) and its siblings.

For example, the first line of the `loadUsers` method could be changed from

> ```
>  var result = await axios.get(url)
> ```

To the following, which can't be re-assigned:

```
    const result = await axios.get(url)
```

3. I would also consider using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) for the query input - i.e.

> ```
>  <input type="text" @input="updateQuery" :value="query">
> ```

updated to:

```
    <input type="text" v-model="query">
```

But I am not sure about replicating the [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) effect in `updateQuery()`... maybe that could be achieved with a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) (perhaps making it more complicated).